Percentage by row total (similar to excel) in power BI
I have a table by categories and Year and I would calculate the category percentage by row total as in the attached pbi. I have only one table
I use:
% of Total Measure = DIVIDE ( CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Qtà fallita] ) ), CALCULATE ( SUM ( Table1[Qtà fallita] ), ALL ( Table1[Error type 2], Table1[Year] )),0)

But it doesn't work

The picture did not upload successfully. pls provide some sample data (not the screenshot) and the expected output.
